# can i call library functions of Objective C in Corona sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, lua, coronasdk

i need to call functions written in objective-C language in corona sdk based on Lua language. Is there any way to do this ??

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay then you can go for [Corona Enterprise](http://coronalabs.com/products/enterprise/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to building a bridge between Objective-C and lua.

This allows you to call a method in Objective-C from Lua script.

[Lua-Objective-C-Bridge](https://github.com/torus/Lua-Objective-C-Bridge)

Comment: but i want to work in corona sdk, where i need to call objective C library function in LUA code?